# In Android It's not signing out and going on login page

Tags: android

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.edit().clear().commit();
//Intent i = new Intent(FriendList.this,Login.class);
//startActivity(i);
this.finish();
Intent i = new Intent(FriendList.this,Login.class);
startActivity(i);

this.onDestroy();*/
```

Comment: you are finishing the activity before the intent is fired, naturally it will not go.

Comment: Sorry sir, Stil not working

Comment: show your FriendList and Login fully.

Comment: is login defined in manifest?

Comment: remove this.destroy() and this.finish()

Comment: removinf distro and finish is also not worked

Comment: I am changing the code. Posting full code now. please go through it.

Comment: sorry guys can't paste whole code.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this answer helps you:

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    settings.edit().clear().commit();
    Intent i = new Intent(FriendList.this,Login.class);
    startActivity(i);
```